# Removing all the images in a control group

Tags: c#, button, foreach, controls

I don't get the option `.Image` when I apply this code:

```
foreach(Control b in _SelectionPanel.Controls)
{
    if (b is Button)
    {
       b.Image = null;
    }
}
```

However, I can get the option 'Visible':

```
foreach(Control b in _SelectionPanel.Controls)
{
    if (b is Button)
    {
       b.Visible = false;
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to remove all the images from the buttons in a control group. Any ideas?

Comment: This is winforms? Whatever it is, if `Control` doesn't have an `Image` property, but the actual runtime type of `b` does, you need to cast the reference to the actual runtime type.

Comment: `(b as button).Image = null;`

Comment: L.B: That unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: ED: Yes I'm using WinForms and okay thanks.

Comment: @RichardJacobs Yes it is a lazy code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` only checks if the type is Button.

You want to use `as` to perform the actual cast, hence allowing you to access Button's properties. If the cast is invalid, you will simply get a `null` reference, so simply perform the `as` cast, then check if your variable is null before using it.

```
foreach(Control b in _SelectionPanel.Controls)
{
    Button castB = b as Button;
    if (castB != null)
    {
        castB.Image = null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Your reply wasn't here when I started writting mine.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. I'll accept this answer when the limit has gone.

Comment: Matheus Rocha: Thanks anyway! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your loop, `b` is a control. Even after checking. To get the Image property, you need to cast it to the Button type:

```
foreach(Control b in _SelectionPanel.Controls)
{
    if (b is Button)
    {
        ((Button)b).Image = null;
        //Alternatively
        (b as Button).Image = null;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var b in _SelectionPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    ((Button)b).Image = null;
}
```

You can iterate over controls of type button only and then explicitly cast var to Button.

Comment: You could also use `foreach(Button b in _selectionPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>())` so that you don't have to cast it in the code.

Comment: Thanks, actually I didn't know that, just to avoid the compilation error(I thought it will give error) I wrote that